# Doubt about finding the largest volume of a parallelepiped inscribed in an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, volume, lagrange-multiplier, quadrics

Searching on the internet, I have seen that this problem can be solvable using the method of Lagrange multipliers, being the Cartesian equation of the ellipsoid the one constraint. But I cannot understand how the people came to know the points of the parallelepiped, especially because I am awful visualizing tridimensional forms, and I can't understand why the equation of the quadric is a constraint either.

For example, when the equation of the ellipsoid is x²/a² + y²/b² + z²/c² = 1, people wrote that the points of the parallelepiped are (±x, ±y, ±z). This is very confusing. Why are these the points? However, the conclusion that the volume is 8|x||y||z|, assuming that those points are really true, is easy to grasp.

Comment: If it was a sphere, would it be obvious that the maximum volume parallelepiped must be a cuboid with all eight vertices on the sphere?  If so, there will still be a cuboid which is a maximum volume parallelepiped if the sphere is stretched into an ellipse (just rotate the sphere's cuboid so its axes are parallel to to the axes you are going to use to stretch the sphere).

Comment: I would guess that for a sphere the maximum volume is comes from a cube with sides $\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}r$ i.e. with volume $\frac{8}{\sqrt{27}}r^3$. So the volume of the maximum volume parallelepiped in an ellipsoid would be $\frac{8}{\sqrt{27}}abc$ where $a,b,c$ are half the lengths of the axes of the ellipsoid, or $\frac{2}{\pi \sqrt{3}} \approx 0.36755$ times the volume of the ellipsoid